# I've been stomped for a couple days now, why is this not returning anything?

Tags: reactjs

the initialState/loggedState methods seem to not be working... nothing will return

Can anyone point out what I did wrong? I'm stomped literally about to call it a day

...

Also useState works (kinda) but whenever I update the page it reverts back to initialState

ps. StackOverflow should let us post no matter how much code we have

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import './Home.css'
import {Card, Figure} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Data from './Data'
import {useMoralis} from 'react-moralis'


function Today()   {
    const { user }  = useMoralis();

    const initialState = (
        <div className='status'>
             <p>Guest</p>
         </div>
    )
     const loggedState =  (
         
        <div className='status'>
               <p>@</p>
           </div>
     )
                    
    const value = useEffect(() => {
        if (user ) {
            return(loggedState)
        } else {
        return(initialState)
    }})


    const current = new Date();

    const date = `${current.getDate()}/${current.getMonth()+1}/${current.getFullYear()}`;
        return(
            <div>
                <div className='top'>

                    <Card style={{ width: '100%' }} >
                        <Card.Body>
                                <Card.Title><span className='card-titled'>Home</span></Card.Title>
                                <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">Dashboard</Card.Subtitle>
                                <Card.Text>
                                    Date: {date}
                                </Card.Text>
                        </Card.Body>
                        <Card.Body className='bannerlogo'>
                                <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/05/Ethereum_logo_2014.svg/73px-Ethereum_logo_2014.svg.png' alt="Girl in a jacket" width="60" height="90" />
                        </Card.Body>
                        <Card.Body className='profilepic'>
                        <Figure>
                            <Figure.Image
                                width={60}
                                height={70}
                                alt="171x180"
                                src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-UI5bnoLTRAE/VuU18_s6bRI/AAAAAAAADGA/uafLtb4ICCEK8iO3NOh1C_Clh86GajUkw/s320/guest.png"
                            />
                             <Figure.Caption>
                                {value}
                             </Figure.Caption>
                            </Figure>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                </div>

            <Data/>
            </div>
        )

}
export default Today
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use useEffect. you have useMolaris is custom hook already

```
function Today()   {
    const { user }  = useMoralis();

    const InitialState = (
        <div className='status'>
             <p>Guest</p>
         </div>
    )
     const LoggedState =  (
         
        <div className='status'>
               <p>@</p>
           </div>
     )
                    

    const current = new Date();

    const date = `${current.getDate()}/${current.getMonth()+1}/${current.getFullYear()}`;


      //Put conditional rendering if there's no user in functional component 
      if(!user) return <InitialState  /> 

        return(
            <div>
                <div className='top'>

                    <Card style={{ width: '100%' }} >
                        <Card.Body>
                                <Card.Title><span className='card-titled'>Home</span></Card.Title>
                                <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">Dashboard</Card.Subtitle>
                                <Card.Text>
                                    Date: {date}
                                </Card.Text>
                        </Card.Body>
                        <Card.Body className='bannerlogo'>
                                <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/05/Ethereum_logo_2014.svg/73px-Ethereum_logo_2014.svg.png' alt="Girl in a jacket" width="60" height="90" />
                        </Card.Body>
                        <Card.Body className='profilepic'>
                        <Figure>
                            <Figure.Image
                                width={60}
                                height={70}
                                alt="171x180"
                                src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-UI5bnoLTRAE/VuU18_s6bRI/AAAAAAAADGA/uafLtb4ICCEK8iO3NOh1C_Clh86GajUkw/s320/guest.png"
                            />
                             <Figure.Caption>
                                {value}
                             </Figure.Caption>
                            </Figure>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                </div>

            <Data/>
            </div>
        )

}
export default Today
```